Azure Rest api to get the information of release pipeline when CI and CD are not in single pipeline
Do we have any azure rest api which can provide the data related to Associated pipelines. I have CI and CD pipeline .First I do CI pipeline and then use CD pipeline to use the latest or any other build to deploy to different environment. I want a azure rest api through which I can found which CD pipeline is associated with CI pipeline and deployed on which environment. Both CI and CD pipeline are in yml. it is in Associated pipeline tab

Now I have another use case where I have build pipeline is in yml and release in classic pipeline I want the azure rest api which can tell which classic release pipeline is associated with this CI build pipeline.I can see this under Releases tab but don't know which api can we use to get that


Hi @unknown, have you checked the suggestions below? Are they helpful for you?

Currently, there isn't such REST API can directly provide data of Associated pipelines and Releases. You can refer to the following workarounds.
1. Get data related to the builds in Associated pipelines.

PowerShell Scripts:

$token = "{PAT}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/_apis/Contribution/HierarchyQuery/project/{ProjectName}?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
$body = @'
{
    "contributionIds": [
        "ms.vss-build-web.cd-pipelines-runs-details-for-ci-pipeline-run-data-provider"
    ],
    "dataProviderContext": {
        "properties": {
            "buildId": "{YourCurrentBuildId}",
            "paginationLimit": "100",
            "sourcePage": {
                "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_build/results?buildId={YourCurrentBuildId}&view=ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.deployments-tab",
                "routeId": "ms.vss-build-web.ci-results-hub-route",
                "routeValues": {
                    "project": "{ProjectName}",
                    "viewname": "build-results",
                    "controller": "ContributedPage",
                    "action": "Execute"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
'@
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Post -Headers $head -Body $body -ContentType application/json
$result | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3



Result:


Note:
For YAML CD pipeline, we can't directly know to which environments/stages it deployed since they are defined in the YAML file. If you want to know it, run REST API Timeline - Get. GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=7.1


2. Get data related to the releases in Releases. Use REST API Definitions - List.

Request:
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/Release/definitions?artifactType=Build&artifactSourceId={artifactSourceId}&$top=1?api-version=6.0-preview.4
For artifactSourceId: {projectGuid}:{BuildDefinitionId}.

Get projectGuid from the id in the response body of REST API Projects - Get: GET https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/_apis/projects/{ProjectName}?api-version=7.1
Get BuildDefinitionId from the URL of your current pipeline.



Result:


      ...
      "environments": [
        {
          "id": 40,
          "name": "Dev",
      ...
      "triggers": [
        {
          "artifactAlias": "_Repo1-PublishArtifact",
          "triggerConditions": [],
          "triggerType": "artifactSource"
        }
      ],
      ...
      "id": 24,
      "name": "DownloadArtifactFromRepo1",
      ...

